# Create a custom file attachment for an email from a string

Tags: c#, email, encryption

What I want to do is to create a mail attachment from a string file and give it my own custom extension.

```
    public void CreateAttachment(string encryptedString, string fileName)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(encryptedString, fileName));
    }
```

I want to create a ".bzk" file and it's gonna be opened in a mobile Android application later. How do I do this? I know there are different constructors as you can see [here!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx)

I do not know what constructors I have to use and even after trying different MIME types and Encodings, it won't work. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

edit:

I've solved my problem. Here is my solution:

```
public void CreateAttachment(string encryptedString, string fileName)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(
            ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedString)
        );

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, new ContentType("text/bzk"));
        attachment.Name = fileName + ".bzk";

        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Here is my solution:

```cs
public void CreateAttachment(string encryptedString, string fileName)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedString)
    );

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, new ContentType("text/bzk"));
    attachment.Name = fileName + ".bzk";

    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loosing the last string argument (`filename`).

I assume the following

- `string encryptedString` is the encrypted content of the file
- `string fileName` is the name you want the attachment to have.

If this is correct, then what I would do is, first create the file with the filename, and then attach the file.

Comment: I've added my solution to the post.