# How do I use Xamarin.Android to open a certain file type with my app?

Tags: android, file, email, xamarin.android

I'm working on an app and I want to open my own custom file type (.bzk) with my app. The way I create it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889234/create-a-custom-file-attachment-for-an-email-from-a-string). I am using Xamarin.Forms to create this app and I am stuck right now. I have found this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/70afe08654927befb26b) which should help but I have no idea how it works. I can't really find a lot of documentation about it, either.

I want my app to appear in [this list](http://www.techsupportalert.com/files/images/pc_freeware/android_apps/Default-App-200-153.jpg).

Does anyone have any samples or some other information which could help me out with this problem?